# Error on dlclose: "shared objects still referenced"

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, posix, qnx

I have the following error on a dlclose()'d .so: "Shared objects still referenced". I didn't find too much information about it. Did you have such a problem before? What kind of programming errors (or compiling options?) can cause this?

The only thing I tried is to find if MY module has successfully released all of the referenced shared objects, but all of them was ok as I see. At least hopefully. I could not really use LD_DEBUG yet.

Comment: Did you use `strace` or `ltrace` ?

Comment: Do you `dlopen()` multiple libraries? Do you pass `RTLD_GLOBAL` when opening any of them?

Comment: Well, this is a two factor thing. In my module, I did an RTLD_GLOBAL load of an so, but that gave this error, so I changed it to LOCAL. The error disappeared in mine. BUT: another module loads mine with LOCAL (as far as I know), but that still gives the error.

Comment: Do you pass `RTLD_NOW` or `RTLD_LAZY` when loading the library?

Comment: It'a RTLD_NOW with RTLD_LOCAL to load my module.

Comment: @newhouse: Do you load any libraries after the library you're trying to `dlclose()`? In that case, try passing `RTLD_LAZY` when loading those. This is just a wild guess, but they might be accidentally resolving some stuff from your library, and `RTLD_LAZY` could possibly prevent that if those things are never actually used.

Comment: @Ulfalizer:That was another guess on our side, so we used a strict visibility on our library, enabling only a few methods to be extracted as a global symbol. A question then: could you tell me an exact example, how to do an error like this?

Comment: @newhouse: It was a bit long for comments, so I included it as an answer. No guarantees that it will generate the warning, but it might (and also shows how undefined references can end up in libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find "Shared objects still referenced" error message in Linux or in opensource libraries. This message only mentioned in context of QNX.

This QT patch https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/4af257eb3cfeef93adefda5f981742ffb58ba0ad  says that this error is informative and can be ignored

> On QNX that's only "informative"
>
> Shared objects still referenced" dlerror should actually be treated as "for your information" only, not as an actual error.

We can say more about error only with additional information:

- debug logs (DL_DEBUG - http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/d/dlopen.html)
- or the source of QNX recent dl libraries (QNX now is closed-source and there *should* be no source of it and its libs in the Internet; you should ask current QNX owners for support or sources licensing)

Comment: Well, then I say, we can live with this. It would be better to know what does it mean actually though, because if it just means that "somebody is holding another reference", then we still have a problem. AFAIK only one module loads us with dlopen, so how can it be, that there is still a reference on the .so?

Answer (score 2):

*(Posting re. discussion in the question's comments.)*

The following *might* trigger that error/warning on QNX. We first need two shared libraries:

- *shared_needs.c*

  ```c
  /* References a function defined elsewhere. */

  void defined_elsewhere(void);

  void f(void) {
      defined_elsewhere();
  }
  ```
- *shared_has.c*

  ```c
  /* Has the function referenced above. */

  void defined_elsewhere(void) {}
  ```

We compile them as follows (with `sonames` and other good practice omitted to keep things simple):

```c
$ gcc -shared -fPIC shared_has.c -o shared_has.so
$ gcc -shared -fPIC shared_needs.c -o shared_needs.so
```

We now load/unload the libraries with the following code (*loader.c*),

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    void *shared_has;

    /* Pass RTLD_GLOBAL so that defined_elsewhere() becomes
       available to libraries loaded later. */
    shared_has = dlopen("shared_has.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (shared_has == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    /* shared_needs.so resolves defined_elsewhere() from
       shared_has.so. */    
    if (dlopen("shared_needs.so", RTLD_NOW) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    /* Might get warning here on QNX, since defined_elsewhere()
       is still used. */
    if (dlclose(shared_has) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

, which we compile and run as follows:

```c
$ gcc loader.c -ldl -o loader
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./loader
```

The above might print the warning on QNX. It should be safe though (as it is on Linux), as the `dlclose()` man page on QNX says the following:

> An object won't be removed from the address space until all references to that object (via dlopen() or dependencies from other objects) have been closed.

As a side note, you can run `objdump -T shared_needs.so` to see that *shared_needs.so* has an undefined reference to `defined_elsewhere()` (look for ****UND****).

Comment: Thanks, that's a fine example.