# What can make dlclose() fail?

Tags: c, dll, posix, dlopen, system-error

On a POSIX (or GNU) system, what can make the [`dlclose()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlclose) function fail?

I know that it fails on repeat-close; and that it misbehaves on a null pointer argument (got a segmentation violation on my system). But are there other situations it can fail?

Edit: I tried looking at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/dlfcn/) and was kind of stumped - could not really figure out where to look (`dlclose.c` is not the place apparently).

Comment: possibly if some other thing is keeping the shared object open? as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882298/error-on-dlclose-shared-objects-still-referenced

Answer (score -1):

The actual implementation is [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/elf/dl-close.c.html).

Look for calls to `_dl_signal_error()` -- there are two.

Comment: Just noticed your answer, and will look into this, but - remember the norm on SO is to write the answers into the body of the post, rather than have them away via a link. PS - not my downvote.